# Hide custom payment method based off product attribute

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.1.12

I'm using a custom module which already hides a payment method based off the quote grand total and a variable defined in the backend. But I need to also do another check, which will see if the product in the session quote contains a certain attribute and then show/hide the payment method.

This is what the file that determines this currently looks like:

```
class Pay4Later extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod {

/**
 * Payment code
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_code = 'pay4later';

/**
 * Availability option
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_isOffline = true;

protected $_isInitializeNeeded = true;

public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null){
    $required_cart = round(($this->getConfigData('min_loan')/90)*100);
    if($quote && $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() > $required_cart) {
        return true;
    } else { 
        return false; 
    }
}

public function getConfigPaymentAction()
{
    return ($this->getConfigData('order_status') == 'pending_payment')? null : parent::getConfigPaymentAction();
} }
```

I've tried to dump the `$quote` variable, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quote, so you can easily get the product. Try the following way:

```
if ($quote) {
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        error_log($product->getSku());
    }
}
```

**Note: use your custom attribute instead of sku**

Comment: Wow... I feel silly. I've been struggling for ages to dump `$quote` on the page. Didn't think about using `error_log`! That worked straight away... thanks a lot.